# Timeout in airflow DockerOperator

Tags: python, docker, airflow, dockeroperator

I am new to Airflow.
I am trying to run a container by an Airflow, but getting a timeout error:

```
[2021-07-21 07:02:06,176] {docker.py:231} INFO - Starting docker container from image python:3.9.2-slim
[2021-07-21 07:03:06,171] {taskinstance.py:1501} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1379, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 311, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 735, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 428, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='host.docker.internal', port=2375): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1157, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1331, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1361, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 319, in execute
    return self._run_image()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 258, in _run_image
    tty=self.tty,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 430, in create_container
    return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 440, in create_container_from_config
    res = self._post_json(u, data=config, params=params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 296, in _post_json
    return self._post(url, data=json.dumps(data2), **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 233, in _post
    return self.post(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='host.docker.internal', port=2375): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
[2021-07-21 07:03:06,179] {taskinstance.py:1551} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=etl_in_ch, task_id=etl_in_ch, execution_date=20210721T070203, start_date=20210721T070205, end_date=20210721T070306
[2021-07-21 07:03:06,215] {local_task_job.py:149} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I have Mac system, and have configured docker socket as shown here: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/issues/543#issuecomment-741842728

My code for Airflow is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

default_args = {
'owner'                 : 'airflow',
'description'           : 'Extract data from different sources into CH and train model with it',
'depend_on_past'        : False,
'start_date'            : datetime(2021, 7, 19),
'email_on_failure'      : False,
'email_on_retry'        : False,
'retries'               : 1,
'retry_delay'           : timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG('etl_in_ch', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="00 23 * * *", catchup=False) as dag:
    start_dag = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start_dag'
        )

    end_dag = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end_dag'
        )

    t1 = DockerOperator(
        task_id='etl_in_ch',
        image='python:3.9.2-slim',
        container_name='etl_in_ch',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        command="apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron && apt-get install -y libxml2 libxslt-dev wget bzip2 gcc \
                && pip install --no-cache-dir  --upgrade pip \
                && pip install --no-cache-dir poetry==1.1.5 \
                && poetry config virtualenvs.create false\
                && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi \
                && chmod +x /src/__main__.py \
                && python __main__.py",
        docker_url="tcp://host.docker.internal:2375",
        network_mode="bridge",
        environment={"PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE": 1, "PYTHONUNBUFFERED": 1},
        working_dir="/usr/src/copy_data",
        mounts=['./CH_ETL/src:/usr/src/copy_data', './pyproject.toml:pyproject.toml'],
        xcom_all=True
    )


    start_dag >> t1

    t1 >> end_dag
```

I saw that I may need to increase a docker timeout, but I do not understand exactly where, and I actually have tried already - on my machine, inside airflow-worker, inside bobrik/socat docker. Did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment in Puckel image comment shows kinda complex solution.

If you have local docker that you want to use from within container, I think much better solution will be to switch to the official image of Apache airflow https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/index.html and use Docker-in-Docker Solution where you map your docker socket to inside the container.

If you have remote docker engine, you are better of with explicitly specifying remote docker engine URL.

You need to make sure you get the right permissions (see for example https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-daemon-access-within-docker-as-non-root-user-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-docker-daemon-socket/94181) or run Airflow as root user (you can do it as of 2.0.2 release I think).

Note that there is a bug in recent release of docker provider for Airflow 2.0.0 (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/index.html) that will generally prevent you from running DockerOperator via either Docker-in-Docker or remote URL. You can either use previous version of the provider or wait for a fix that's coming in 2.1.0 https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16932

Comment: Hi, Thank you I will try.
I actually started from "map your docker socket to inside the container", but I was keepinig getting error FileNotFound.

Comment: For the docker for Airflow, I took suggested by them docker-compose file: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

Comment: In this docker-compose there are many services, I do not know actually which one is the most important, and to which should I map the socket (I did try inside airflow-worker)

Comment: Yeah. Worker is good. You can read more about the services/architecture here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/overview.html

Comment: I actually have already airflow 2.1.2, so DockerOperator should be fixed? I also have mac, that's why I think solution with Puckel image comment, is best for me, configuring permissions is not so easy on mac. What I think can be blocking, can be are proxy setting in docker?

Comment: Nope. the DockerOperator with the fix is not yet released (and it's in the Provider which can be upgraded independently from the airflow release). I have no idea what can blocker there, but I believe  mounting socket is your best bet. I've done that on Mac multiple times and never had any problems with it. As mentioned before - Airlfow 2.1.2 can be run as root user, then no permissions for socket need to be modified.

Comment: I do not really understand, what you mean by "Airlfow 2.1.2 can be run as root user" when it is started within a docker container? I actually checked, I can start docker inside the airflow-worker in python, so yes, problem must be with airflow. How can I downgrade the provider? I do not see any settings for that in docker-compose: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.2/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: I did manage to downgrade apache-airflow-providers-docker, but ist it compatible with airflow:2.1.2? How can I check it (webinterface failed to start, so it is not compatible...but which version is?)?

Comment: I think all versions of the providers released are compatible with 2.1.2. There are a few providers that require 2.1+ but generally speaking you can use even older versions of providers with latest Airflow.

Comment: You know, I think downgrading worked...it is just the sevices are now marked "unhealthy" if I restart docker-compose

Comment: The docker-compose we have is more of a quick-start. As you can read in the docs and in the docker-compose itself, it's not supposed to be used in production (it's not been battle-tested). So some things like that might not be rock-solid. We recommend (and support) Official Helm chart deployment at Apache Airflow wiht K8S : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html